# Strapi API Error {"data":null,"error":{"status":404,"name":"NotFoundError","message":"Not Found","details":{}}}

Tags: strapi

I've Strapi 4.
I'm getting error for API call

```
http://localhost:1337/api/customers/:1

{
    "data": null,
    "error": {
        "status": 404,
        "name": "NotFoundError",
        "message": "Not Found",
        "details": {}
    }
}
```

For customers the API works fine

```
http://localhost:1337/api/customers
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "attributes": {
                "firstname": "John",
                "createdAt": "2023-11-18T21:30:47.920Z",
                "updatedAt": "2023-11-18T21:52:02.386Z",
                "publishedAt": "2023-11-18T21:31:46.731Z",
                "lastname": "Does"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "attributes": {
                "firstname": "Lilly",
                "createdAt": "2023-11-18T21:31:38.210Z",
                "updatedAt": "2023-11-18T21:52:17.782Z",
                "publishedAt": "2023-11-18T21:31:41.103Z",
                "lastname": "Filly"
            }
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
        "pagination": {
            "page": 1,
            "pageSize": 25,
            "pageCount": 1,
            "total": 2
        }
    }
}
```

I've set the roles on USERS & PERMISSIONS PLUGIN -> Roles, see the screenshot below.
Am I missing anything else? How to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are going to the wrong url. In this url, `/:id` is given as an example for you and you must have forgotten to delete it.
change this

```
http://localhost:1337/api/customers/:1
```

to

```
http://localhost:1337/api/customers/1
```

Comment: man I feel so stupid ;) thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Don't feel :) that's normal you just missed it.